# JBoss system property replacement does not work

Tags: java, xml, jboss

My JBoss version is Jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.
I have some system properties in `standalone.xml`:

```
<system-properties>
        <property name="ims.eas.service.registerSystem" value="registerSystem"/>        
        <property name="ims.developerMode" value="false"/>
        ...
</system-properties>
```

In `web.xml` refer to them as `${ims.developerMode}`. But it does not work.
Watched `System.getProperties()` in debug mode, system properties are there. It reads them from `standalone.xml` but not replaces in `web.xml`. With `jboss-eap-6.1` it works pretty well.

Comment: I hope you are not making changes while the server is running.

Comment: No, i'm not making changes while the server is running

Comment: I guess there is an issue with jboss 7.1.1. You may try reading the content in jboss-web.xml. Also check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032095/references-to-systemproperties-in-web-xml-and-jboss-web-xml-works-in-jboss5-but hope it helps.